# Latest Debian 8 Updates Hosed KDE

Tags: debian, kde, bugs

System Information

- Current Kernel Version: `4.0.0-2-amd64`
- Version: 8 (output of `cat /etc/debian_version` is `stretch/sid`, i.e. testing release, codename stretch)
- KDE: 4.14.2 (Qt: 4.8.7)

After the last set of updates, I'm having the following issues in KDE:

- Opening applications does not show a menu bar, the application is somehow bound to the taskbar (no close/minimize options, window cannot be moved)
- No desktop switching
- Cannot type into the search bar
- Cannot type into dropdown terminal that automatically starts (but *can* type into standard Terminal application)
- Cannot type into anything tied to the task bar except for newly launched applications to include the Iceweasel browser and Terminal.
- Cannot switch between applications (they bind themselves to the taskbar and you can't get to other applications including the 'start menu')

KDE has essentially become useless as a desktop environment for me. How do I fix this? Is this a known issue? What additional information do I need to provide?

I couldn't find other bug reports related to this so I wanted to check if there is something I am missing before filing any.

Comment: I've seen something similar to this, a long time ago (so I don't recall the details) on a non-KDE, non-Linux system (so, even if I did remember the details, they probably wouldn't help you).  As I recall, the problem was that the X server was running but the window manager wasn't.  Maybe this clue will be enough to point somebody in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried reinstall KDE and xorg: `aptitude reinstall xserver-xorg kde-plasma-desktop`?

Comment: @McSinyx I just tried and got this error: `Can't find a source to download version '5:84' of 'kde-plasma-desktop:amd64'`.

Comment: I see the package [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/kde/kde-plasma-desktop) but for some reason aptitude can't find it.

Comment: Need `/etc/apt/sources.list` please. And you're not on Jessie, you are on Stretch or Sid now.

Comment: @McSinyx aha, I managed to do it. I use the yakuake dropdown shell rather than terminal. For some reason that package manager in standard Terminal wasn't grabbing all sources properly. I installed kde-full then rebooted, then reinstalled xserver-xorg and kde-plasma-desktop from yakuake and it now works. weird

Comment: It has a different look and feel, upgraded perhaps but it didn't take initially? Or maybe downgraded haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it says stretch/sid, you're not *actually* using debian 8, you're using either stretch (which will become debian 9 in about a year or two) or unstable. Given your predicament, I suspect the latter.

Unstable is currently in the midst of a [transition to gcc5](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2015/08/msg00000.html), which breaks everything C++-related. In addition, the KDE maintainers have decided to use this opportunity to migrate to the latest version of plasma desktop, which has started yesterday, but is far from complete. You currently have components of two KDE versions running together, which (as you've discovered) doesn't work so well.

You essentially have three options:

1. Ride it out; keep using unstable. It will be a rough ride. Don't blindly upgrade, but check what's happening when you upgrade. If you do this, make sure you subscribe to the debian-devel-announce mailinglist, where this sort of thing is usually annnounced.
2. Switch your `sources.list` files to stretch (i.e., testing). You will still get fairly regular upgrades -- except when these sorts of transitions are happening; but then they won't be as rough.
3. Switch to jessie (i.e., stable) In jessie, this sort of thing is *guaranteed* not to happen. Doing that will require you to reinstall, though.